# Flutter - Range Slider

Tags: widget, flutter, flutter-layout

How to create a range slider in Flutter like below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: they are making this [one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18083)

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

A range slider with two thumbs seems to be work in progress https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18083#issuecomment-394404567

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Just saw that `one` in the comments points to the same issue :D

Answer (score 1):

There is another package with more customization options

[https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_xlider](http://Flutter%20Xlider)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/boeledi/RangeSlider

i used this one for creating a range slider in flutter.